# Is this set of sequences countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the metric space $l^p$, with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$,
the space of sequences $x = (\xi_j)$ of real number such that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty {\left|\xi_j \right|^p} < \infty.
$$
The metric is defined by
$$
d(x,y) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty {\left|\xi_j - \eta_j \right|^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
where $x = (\xi_j)$ and $y = (\eta_j)$.

Let $M$ be the set of all sequences $y$ of the form
$$
y = (\eta_1, \eta_2, \dots, \eta_n, 0, 0, 0, \dots)
$$
where $n$ is any positive integer and the $\eta_j$'s are rational numbers.

Is the set $M$ countable?

Comment: Yes: there’s a pretty evident bijection between $M$ and $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb Q^n$, which is the union of countably many countable sets.

Comment: $d(x,y)$ should be the $p$th root of your definition.

Comment: The only question here is independent of $\ell^p$, it would seem - you could just start this question with the paragraph "Let $M$ be ..." Possibly the rest of the question asks if $M$ is dense in $\mathbb \ell^p$?

Comment: You are right, Thomas. The rest of the question asks if $M$ is dense in $\ell^p$ and it is true. But, to me, the main obscure point was how to prove that $M$ is countable. Brian's comment clarified it.